# Applying jQuery sortable only to selected elements

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to implement a drag and drop functionality using ui-sortable. However, of the 3 `<li>`'s that I have, I want only the 1st and last to be able to exchange their positions, the one in the center should maintain it's position. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the appropriate selector in the [items](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-items) options:

```
$("#yourElement").sortable({
    items: "li:first-child, li:last-child"
});
```